# Network Error while connecting Axios to React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

Api import:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const Api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'exp://IP:19000' });
export default Api;
```

Component where I'm using it:

```
const handlePress = async () => {
    try {
      await TaskService.create({ title: title })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

I was getting a warning before, but after I used trycatch I started to get this error:
Network Error

Stack trace:
node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:14 in createError
node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:84:24 in handleError
node_modules/event-target-shim/dist/event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
[native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0):

try to use .then() .catch() promise